# Address already in use for puma-dev

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, puma, macos-monterey, puma-dev

### Problem

Whenever I try to run

```
bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb --port 5000
```

I keep getting

```
bundler: failed to load command: puma (/Users/ogirginc/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.2/bin/puma)
Errno::EADDRINUSE: Address already in use - bind(2) for "0.0.0.0" port 5000
```

### Tried Things

I have tried anything I can think of or read. Here is the list:

**1. Good old restart the mac.**

- Nope.

**2. Find PID and kill.**

- Run `lsof -wni tcp:5000`

```
COMMAND    PID     USER   FD   TYPE            DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
ControlCe 6071 ogirginc   20u  IPv4 0x1deaf49fde14659      0t0  TCP *:commplex-main (LISTEN)
ControlCe 6071 ogirginc   21u  IPv6 0x1deaf49ec4c9741      0t0  TCP *:commplex-main (LISTEN)
```

- Kill with `sudo kill -9 6071`.
- When I kill it, it is restarted with a new PID.

```
> lsof -wni tcp:5000
COMMAND    PID     USER   FD   TYPE            DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
ControlCe 6071 ogirginc   20u  IPv4 0x1deaf49fde14659      0t0  TCP *:commplex-main (LISTEN)
ControlCe 6071 ogirginc   21u  IPv6 0x1deaf49ec4c9741      0t0  TCP *:commplex-main (LISTEN)
```

**3. Use HTOP to find & kill**

- Filter with `puma`.
- Found a match.

```
PID USER      PRI  NI  VIRT   RES S CPU% MEM%   TIME+  Command
661 ogirginc   17   0  390G  6704 ?  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 /opt/homebrew/bin/puma-dev -launchd -dir ~/.puma-dev -d localhost -timeout 15m0s -no-serve-public-paths
```

- Kill it with `sudo kill -9 661`.
- Restarted with a new PID.

**Additional Info**

- rails version is `5.2.6`.
- puma version is `4.3.8`.
- puma-dev version is `0.16.2`.
- Here are the logs for puma-dev:

```
2021/10/26 09:48:14 Existing valid puma-dev CA keypair found. Assuming previously trusted.
* Directory for apps: /Users/ogirginc/.puma-dev
* Domains: localhost
* DNS Server port: 9253
* HTTP Server port: inherited from launchd
* HTTPS Server port: inherited from launchd
! Puma dev running...
```

It feels like I am missing something obvious. <s>Probably, due to lack of understanding some critical & lower parts of `puma-dev`.</s> I would really appreciate, if this is solved with some simple explanation. Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

### Why

Well, this is interesting. I did not think of searching for  `lsof`'s `COMMAND` column, before.

Turns out, `ControlCe` means "Control Center" and beginning with Monterey, macOS does listen ports `5000` & `7000` on default.

### Solution

1. Go to System Preferences > Sharing
2. Uncheck `AirPlay Receiver`.
3. Now, you should be able to restart `puma` as usual.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/682332